# memory management issues in xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, memory-management, xamarin.ios, garbage-collection, automatic-ref-counting

As far as I have worked in xamarin declaring global variables in view controller is very important or else it can be garbage collected when it comes to Binding and all concerned.

likewise for nsnotification we have to have a global reference of nsobject type and remove the nsobject when we don't need nsnotification.

there are no practical documentation available and making native iOS developers to get frustrated with xamarin.ios

Suggesting few things like this would be a good help for any ios developer who becomes xamarin.ios developer

Answer (score 0):

In Every ViewControllers Write following Code:

```
public override void ViewDidDisappear (bool animated)
{
    //Executed when we navigate to other view, moving this ViewController in Navigation stack

    //1. UnSubscribe All Events Here (Note: These must be SubScribed back in ViewWillAppear)
    btnLogin.TouchupInside -= OnLoginClicked
    //2. Remove Any TapGuestures (Note: These must be added back in ViewWillAppear)
    if (singleTapGuesture != null)
    {
       scrollView.RemoveGestureRecognizer(singleTapGuesture);
       singleTapGuesture.Dispose();
       singleTapGuesture = null;
    }
    //3. Remove any NSNotifications (Note: These must be added back in ViewWillAppear)
    //4. Clear anything here, which again initializes in ViewWillAppear


    if (ParentViewController == null) {
        //This section will be executed when ViewController is Removed From Stack
        //1. Clear everything here
        //2. Clear all Lists or other such objects
        //3. Call Following Method which will clear all UI Components 
        ReleaseDesignerOutlets ();
    }
    base.ViewDidDisappear (animated);
}
```

This will clear out all unwanted object when ViewController is Navigated or Removed from the stack.

For UITableViews, use WeakDataSource & WeakDelegate.

There can be many more based on following Links:

[Ref 1](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/memory_perf_best_practices/)

[Ref 2](https://thomasbandt.com/xamarinios-memory-pitfalls)